# Nonestraight segments in a vector space

Tags: vector-spaces

Is there a vectorial structure on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that the segments $[x,y]$ with boundary points $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^2$ are not graphically straight?

$[x,y]$ is defined as $\{\lambda x  +(1-\lambda)y : \lambda \in [0,1] \}$.

I have no idea about that, so I'm not looking for exact answers but hints, possible structures to verify.

Comment: How do you define "straight"?

Comment: @KentaS In the usual vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$, when you look at the segments, they are line segments; I'm looking for a vectorial structure so that when I see **graphically** the segments they look not as line segments in the usual sense; for instance, segments that look as arcs of a circle may works.

Comment: So basically you mean that the segments are not the same as the ones in the euclidean 2d vector space, regarding their images, right? Also, I think you meant to have $0 ≤ \lambda ≤ 1$ and $x$ and $y$ reversed.

Comment: @StefanOctavian It's exactly that!

Comment: Well, consider the vector space of real polynomials of degree at most $2$, let $x\colon t\mapsto t$ be the identity and $y\colon t\mapsto t^2$ the square-function.  Then $[x,y]$ ist the set of functions $\{\lambda t+(1-\lambda)t^2\}$

Comment: Take any bijection from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to itself, as horrible as you like. Pass the standard vector space structure through it, and you'll get a vector space structure with line segments which are (on average), about as messy as your bijection was, if looked at from the other side of that bijection.

Comment: @Michael Hopped, OP specified that the carrier set of the vector space must be $\mathbb{R^2}$.